# Can I run more than one server side experiment at the same time on Google Optimize?

Tags: optimization, google-analytics, google-optimize

Is it ok to run more than one experiment at the same time?
Is it valid to emit more than one line for experiment.variant in JS code targeting Google Optimize?
For example:

```
-- first test
ga('set', 'exp', 'ExperimentA.Variant1');
-- second test
ga('set', 'exp', 'ExperimentB.Variant1');
```

Clearly, I can't assign exp twice.
At the same time calling

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

after each set would be wrong too since it would result in GA counting the page twice.
Can someone help?